# WKHTMLTOPDF returns nothing

Tags: shell, unix, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to convert a html page to pdf using command-line convertor WKHTMLTOPDF.
It does not return me anything and it does not throw any errors ether.

```
[root@s16271040 var]# grep -i amd /proc/cpuinfo
[root@s16271040 var]# grep -i intel /proc/cpuinfo
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31270 @ 3.40GHz
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31270 @ 3.40GHz
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31270 @ 3.40GHz
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31270 @ 3.40GHz
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31270 @ 3.40GHz
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31270 @ 3.40GHz
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31270 @ 3.40GHz
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31270 @ 3.40GHz

[root@s16271040 bin]# ls -la | grep -i pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    8224273 May 24  2010 wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-i386.tar.bz2
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8218920 May 24  2010 wkhtmltopdf-i386
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root   1000 11446024 Oct  2  2011 wkhtmltopdf-i386_11
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   11414685 Oct  2  2011 wkhtmltopdf-i386.tar.bz2

[root@s16271040 bin]# wkhtmltopdf-i386 http://google.com test.pdf
[root@s16271040 bin]# ls -la | grep -i test.pdf
```

The version I am trying is 0.9.9 taken from http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list
I tried the latest one - 0.11.0. Still no success

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wkhtmltopdf` needs an x instance, possibly provided by xvfb it no real x server is running, as [for instance mentioned here](http://ciaranmcnulty.com/blog/2009/04/converting-html-to-pdf-using-wkhtmltopdf).

In case that link dies in future, something like:

```
xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf --dpi 200 --page-size A4 http://domain.tld/page.html /path/to/output.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

You should at least be getting some form of output. At least an error. Which operating system are you using? If Debian based try apt-get install wkhtmltopdf, if you're on a server and not a desktop, then the above answer is correct, you need a running X11 server or an emulated one such as Xvfb.